# Stack Overflow Teams: Disable Public Q&A?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is it possible to disable public Q&A for a user account to ensure that all questions asked are asked as private team questions?

It seems potentially easy to accidentally post a private question to the public arena.

Comment: Unless you named your team "Public" a user must [have missed plenty of UI hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laWtw.png) that they are posting in the wrong context ...

Comment: @rene:  I would be floored if that *didn't* happen, honestly.  UI cues are only effective if you get someone who's not rushed paying attention to them.

Comment: @Makoto What do you propose? Electric shocks on their keyboard?

Comment: The prospect of being terminated for posting confidential information to a public forum is *plenty* enough electric shock, so...sure!

Comment: @rene Your screenshot illustrates that there are plenty of visual indicators when you **are** posting in a Channel, but almost nothing to warn you that you **are not**.

Comment: I was waiting for that feedback @Jeremy, still: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Llp.png

Comment: @Jeremy would you think having an extra confirmation when you're on a team and posting in public would be valued by users? Because I don't see how you would otherwise prevent this except for blocking it out right, which might be preferred by the Team manager but not so by long standing users.

Comment: @rene There's a confirmation pop-up if you're a member of a team and go to post a question on public: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbCkx.png

Comment: @AdamLear Huh? I guess we have to ask the OP what *It seems potentially easy to accidentally post* means....

Comment: I think if you are a seasoned StackOverflow user, the UI hints probably suffice. But for users who aren't familiar, "public" might lack context. If I have never logged in to StackOverflow before, maybe I interpret that as public within the company? Just as a comparison, a "public" channel in Slack carries much different context. Just the idea that a message could go beyond the company is going to be unintuitive for first-time users is my concern.

Comment: Is there not training provided for users to help them understand how the system works?

Comment: This Q should be flagged for migration to UX.SE. :-/ If you're a seasoned user and have asked many questions, the **only** thing you're looking at is that text box.

Answer (score 2):

Users can still have a separate account for posting on other Stack Exchange sites and this would not prevent them from posting private questions in a public arena. In fact this might make it harder to track down who is accidentally posting private questions where they should not be as there would be no quick link from the public post to the user's private profile.

Comment: Yes, agreed, that this doesn't address the concern of accidental public posts. What I would like is the ability to have a team-specific login that *cannot* make public posts.

Comment: And if it's really that confidential then why are you storing your Q&A on somebody else's computer?

Comment: @AaronKent Having a separate login won't prevent a user from posting private data as they still can end up posting in a public place from a separate account if they are not careful. You can either ban all Stack Exchange sites other then the private teams one or ensure proper training is in place to ensure that users are checking to ensure the post is in the correct area before posting.

Comment: @AaronKent: If you block SO on those accounts, you guarantee that the user will have a second account where they can access SO, and then it'll be even easier to accidentally post the question in the wrong place.

Comment: I have a work account that I log into from my work computer and this personal account which I log into from my personal computer.  On my work account, I've already accidentally edited my public profile when meaning to edit my private team profile.  If there was a positive answer to the original question, it would be an easy solution to prevent accidental disclosure of information.  It's why we still find things like practices like the use of `sudo` useful.