# Can you please not ask me to confirm this is a public question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, stack-overflow-for-teams

As a high-profile user, I'm fairly confident that I don't make mistakes like this:

> [image: System message requiring user to check a box stating the question doesn't contain any private information.]

Even if I ask a question infrequently, this can be annoying.

Can we have an option to disable this prompt every time I ask a question? Or maybe disable this for users above some threshold (say 1k or 10k or so).

Comment: You could have single-handedly written the UI for Stack Exchange and I can guarantee you would still accidentally publicly post a Teams question at some point without that checkbox.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I disagree.

This is probably a feature that's desired by Team clients, and even high-rep users can make simple mistakes.

Checking a single checkbox for every public question you ask also takes very little effort, especially since most high-rep users won't ask questions frequently.

If anything, it should be configurable by the team admin, not the user. Users generally should not be able to disable security measures for a team, even if it only affects them.

Answer (score 11):

Even if we implemented a bypass for it, it would need to be up to the team admins on whether or not to implement it. The second it takes to check the box is small in comparison to having your fancy new GPU firmware picked up by Google a few seconds after someone posts it (and possibly the Internet Archive) and containing that takes, well, way more than a second :)

I don't think it's something we're likely to implement unless there's a serious vocal demand *from the owners of the teams*, but I'm not putting a status tag on it.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said there are reasons for the confirmation box when posting on a public site if you are a member of a private team. In fact there have been requests to be able to prohibit a member of a private team team from being able to post on that account to a public site in order to limit the possibility of posting private material in a public space.

[Stack Overflow Teams: Disable Public Q&A?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376820/stack-overflow-teams-disable-public-qa/376823#comment648349_376823)

While I disagree with going that far I don't think it is unreasonable to have a check to ensure you are posting in the area you expect and judging by answers it appears that I am not the only one who thinks this.